# how to get all rows with max value of a variable

Tags: r, dataframe, max, row, subset

I have matrix containing two columns and many rows. The first column name is `idCombinaison` and the second column name is `accuarcy`. The `accuarcy` has a float values.

Now I want to get all rows which the value of `accuarcy == max value`. In some cases (like depicted in the picture), I can have many rows which the value of `accuarcy` equals to max, so I want to get all these rows!

I tried this:

```
maxAccuracy <- subset(accuarcyMatrix, accuarcyMatrix['accuarcy'] == max(accuarcyMatrix['accuarcy']))
```

But this return an empty vector. Any ideas please? 
[image]

Comment: Please add the data using `dput()` instead of using a picture.

Comment: If your data is a matrix, change `accuarcyMatrix['accuarcy']` to `accuarcyMatrix[, 'accuarcy']` in your code.

Comment: @DarrenTsai, Thank you very much, it is exactly the solution to my problem. if you want post your response in answers section, I will accept it. Thank you !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reproducible data simulating your **matrix**:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- matrix(sample(1:9, 30, T), 10, 3)
row.names(x) <- 1:10
colnames(x) <- LETTERS[1:3]

#    A B C
# 1  3 9 9
# 2  8 5 7
# 3  4 7 6
# ...
```

In matrix objects, you need to use a binary way to extract element such as `data[a, b]`. Take the above data for example, `x["C"]` will return `NA` and `x[, "C"]` will return all elements in column C. Therefore, the following two codes are going to generate different outputs.

```
subset(x, x["C"] == max(x["C"]))
#   A B C (Empty)

subset(x, x[, "C"] == max(x[, "C"]))
#   A B C
# 1 3 9 9
# 4 8 6 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
library(dplyr)
accuarcyMatrix %>%
filter_at(vars(accuarcy),
          any_vars(.==max(.))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution (although this is very likely a duplicate):

```
accuarcyMatrix[ which(accuarcyMatrix$accuarcy == max(accuarcyMatrix$accuarcy) , ]
```

I'm guessing you will want to change "accuarcy" to "accuracy"

Comment: Hey sir, I think your solution is not applicable to a matrix. I guess the OP's data is a matrix.

Comment: I'm not sure where you get that idea. He used `accuarcyMatrix['accuarcy']` which would probably only succeed for a dataframe and certainly would NOT succeed for a matrix whose rows were named as illustrated.

Comment: As shown in my answer, `matrix["name"]` will succeed but return an `NA`. And the OP said his code returns an empty vector, which matches what I reason that the data is a matrix.

Comment: In contrast, if the OP's data is a data frame, his code will work and return what he wants, not an empty vector.

Comment: Ah, the perils of attempting answers when there's no reproducible example. Yet another reason to leave the question closed.